# Clarification on Recursive Fibonacci Time Complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I was following a YouTube video on O(2^n) Time Complexity and this is the code presented:

```js
function fib(n) {
    if (n === 0) return 0;
    if (n === 1) return 1;
    
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

fib(4);
```

In the video it is said that the operations performed for this code are 8 i.e. 2^3.

This is because the recursive fibonacci is actually 2^(n-1), 
and since we exclude constants with BigO we consider it to be O(2^n).

But I really don't get why the number of operations are 8.

I wrote down the recursion tree (by balancing it) for this function.

[image: fib-sequence]

I see that fib() is called 14 times, so wouldn't the operations count be 14? 
Why do we count only the last level?

Comment: `fib(1)` and `fib(0)` do not make recursive calls. The stuff in your box does not actually happen.

Comment: @Pointy hi, as I said, I added them just to balance the tree.

Comment: OK, well it does look nice, but it represents fictional computation.

Comment: Note that if you count all the nodes except the top and the ones in the box, there are 8 of them.

Comment: true, I noticed that, but now I'm wondering why the guy in the video added them tho...it made it more confusing this way...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*recursive fibonacci is actually 2^(n-1)*" and "*the operations performed for this code*"? What do you count as an operation? Do you actually count function calls?

Comment: @Bergi in the video I watched the guy seems to count only return 0 & return 1 as operations and not the function calls, if we do that, it makes sense that the number of operations are 8 assuming this is (to be precise) O(2ⁿ⁻¹) Time Complexity

Answer (score 1):

It looks like everything in that youtube video you watched was wrong.

The recurrence relation for your `fib(n)` is:

T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + O(1)

This is certainly going to be exponential, but certainly not O(2<sup>n</sup>) if you want a tight bound.

Since the O(1) is not important to the overall complexity, we actually have T(n) = O(fib(n)), which is O(φ<sup>n</sup>), where φ is the golden ratio, about 1.618.

When stating exponential complexities, you have to get the base exactly right.

Comment: Should the recurrence relation also have a base case, or is that always implicitly `∀n⩽0:T(n) = O(1)`?

Comment: I would not so easily discard the `O(1)`. Sure, it just leads to a constant factor here, but I wouldn't generalise this.

Comment: I omitted and assumed the base case, since it doesn't matter what it is.

Comment: @MattTimmermans could you please explain why it looks like 2^n complexityin the diagram presented above for fib(4)?There are exactly 8 computation done.

Comment: @hermit It doesn't.  You can't determine a growth rate from one measurement.... and there are 9... or 15 if you count the made up ones... and 2^4 = 16, not 8... and there's an arbitrary constant factor that can be anything at all.  Every single thought presented in the question is wrong.

Comment: Hi matt, thanks for your reply, my doubt was firstly why the operations are not 16 but if we consider this to be O(2ⁿ⁻¹) (as the guy said in the video) and we ignore the wrong fib() calls I added in the square as @Pointy was saying, it makes sense...